# BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implementation hides prometheus system and jvm metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics

I'm using a class that implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor so that I can use the postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry method to instantiate WebClient type beans, add them to the registry and then use them via Autowired and Qualifier(nameBean) in other Class.

Everything's OK except that in the prometheus metrics I don't see any jvm or system type metrics.

I have this class which is called from META-INF/spring via re.test.pos.api.consumer.WebClientInstanceBuilderAutoConfiguration.
This class call the WebClientInstanceBuilder class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ ConsumerProperties.class })
@ConditionalOnClass(WebClient.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(WebClient.Builder.class)
public class WebClientInstanceBuilderAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public WebClientInstanceBuilder webClientInstanceBuilder(Environment environment,
            WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

        WebClientInstanceBuilder webClientInstanceBuilder = new WebClientInstanceBuilder(webClientBuilder);

        return webClientInstanceBuilder;
    }
}
```

I have this class WebClientInstanceBuilder which implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor and its goal is to instantiate the bean in the method postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry

```
public class WebClientInstanceBuilder implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    ConsumerProperties consumerProperties;
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    public WebClientInstanceBuilder(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClientBuilder   = webClientBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {

            String beanKey = "accountManagementWebClient";

            WebClient client = webClientBuilder.clone().baseUrl("https://test.api:8443/test")
                    .codecs( codecs -> {codecs.defaultCodecs();})
                    .build();

            GenericBeanDefinition definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            definition.setBeanClass(WebClient.class);
            definition.setInstanceSupplier(() -> client);
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanKey, definition);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    }

}
```

And I have this class which use the bean accountManagementWebClient

```
@Component
public class AccountManager {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("accountManagementWebClient")
    private WebClient accountWebClient;

    public String getAccountByBillingAccountId(String billingAccountId, String tumUserId) {

        WebClient theAccountWebClient = accountWebClient;

        try {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

Everything is OK except the prometheus metrics.
When I look at the metrics prometheus I don't see the JMV metrics.
I application.properties I have :

```
management.server.port=4242
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.metrics.enable.all=true
```

If I delete the implementation of BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor and I continue to create the WebClient Bean with another solution I can see all the metrics prometheus also the jvm and system metrics.
But in this case I'm having problems with the @Autowired to retrieve the Bean because unfortunately as soon as I delete the implementation of BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor  the Autowired are executed before the instantiation of my beans.

I tried a lot of things but without success.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should not customize the WebClient using a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`, instead you can do this:

```java
@Bean
WebClient accountWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder.baseUrl("https://httpbin.org/get").build();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do without the implementation because, as I've already said, it's managed in an external JAVA library that handles a lot of things automatically. So if I stop using the external library, I'll have to revise a lot of code and redevelop a lot of code.

Comment: The external library should use the builder to set things up for you and let you use that builder to further configure things and create a WebClient instance.